# IAMVideoProcAmp.GetRange() getting 0:0:0:0for ColorEnable

Tags: camera

I'm working with a usb camera under windows. It seems the call of GetRange() gives me the property value for ColorEnable 0:0:0:0.

Is that possible? Does it mean the camera does not support this property or anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any language in particular?

Comment: Scott, I'm using c++.